# Socket.io—about socket disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, socket.io

I have this scenario with socket.io:

I want to receive the data from a sever and Forward the data to webclient.But when I receive a lot of data and close the page, it console

```
DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT
DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT
DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT
DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT
DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT
DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT
DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT
...(a lot)
```

Here is the code:

server:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var net=require('net');
var http=require('http').createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(http);
var net=require('net');
var nodeServer = new net.Socket();
var aSocket=null;

io.on('connection', function (socketIO) {
  aSocket=socketIO;
};
nodeServer.on('data', function(data) {
 if(aSocket!=null){
    aSocket.emit('pushToWebClient',useData);
    aSocket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT');
    });

  }
```

client:

```
socket.on('pushToWebClient', function (useData) {


    });
```

I find

```
aSocket.on('disconnect', function () {
          console.log('DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT');
        });
```

console a lot of'DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT' but actually it should console just once in the code.

I had even console.log(aSocket.id),it console just only one.

I don't know why it is console so many times.

I haved used setMaxListeners(10) to try to avoid it .
Will it lead to a memory leak？

Comment: A socket.io connection from a web page will be disconnected any time the web browser navigates to a new page.  A given connection is tied to a specific page and only to that page.  When the browser leaves that page, all resources from that page are closed and freed.  Typically, the next web page on the same site would just open a new connection that it can use for the duration of that page.

Comment: @jfriend00    I maybe not express clearly...I know your meaning . I just open one page to recieve from a server. when I close the page ,it console a lot of 'DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT'.I had even console.log('aSocket.id'),it was just only one id. This is the most confused me.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are registering multiple event listeners for the same `disconnect` event.  In this code:

```
nodeServer.on('data', function(data) {
 if(aSocket!=null){
    aSocket.emit('pushToWebClient',useData);
    aSocket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT');
    });

  }
```

You appear to be registering a new `disconnect` event listener every time you get a `data` message.  So, if you have multiple listeners, then each one will get called when the socket disconnects and the result is that you will log the same message multiple times all for the same socket.

You can verify this is what is happening by moving your `disconnect` handler into the `connection` handler so it is only ever attached just once for each socket.

In addition putting `asocket` into a global or module-level variable means that your server code would only ever work with one single client at a time. It is not clear exactly what you are trying to do when you get data on the `nodeserver` connection - whether you're trying to send that data to only one specific client or to all connected clients.

Comment: thanks a lot. My English is too poor to express clearly.I had tried to move it to connection handler,it console only once indeed.But if I do this, when `nodeServer` receive `data` from a server,I don't know how to Forward the data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I try to delete the code:

```
aSocket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT');
    });
```

or moving it out of nodeServer handler,

it turn into normal and never suggest me to setMaxlisener.

I think maybe it is incorrect put one API into a API

And the envent maybe not release the socket,so it console multiple times .

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I'm moving this to the top because I saw that someone already provided my solution but you were having a problem managing the data sent to the client. Your `aSocket` variable will be overwritten by every new client that connects to your app. If you want to send data to a specific client using your server `nodeServer`, you should create a global variable (an array) that keeps track of all of your client socket connections. So instead of using one global variable `aSocket` do the following:

```
var net=require('net');
var nodeServer = new net.Socket();
var clients = [];

io.on('connection', function (socketIO) {
    clients.push(socketIO);
    var clientNum = clients.length-1;
    aSocket.on('disconnect', function () {
        clients.splice(clientNum, 1);
        console.log('DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT: '+socketIO.id);
    });
};

nodeServer.on('data', function(data) {
//have your data object contain an identifier for the client that caused the handler to fire
//for the sake of the answer I just use data.id

    var clientID = data.id;
    if(clients[clientID]!=null){
        clients[clientID].emit('pushToWebClient', useData);
    }
}
```

Let me know how it goes! **My original answer is below:**

Try moving

```
aSocket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT');
});
```

out of your `nodeServer.on('data', ...)` event listener into the `io.on('connection', ...)` event listener like so:

```
io.on('connection', function (socketIO) {
    aSocket=socketIO;
    aSocket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT');
    });
};
```

**socket.io** is designed to *keep polling* for the presence of the server/client. If either the server or the client are disconnected, the remaining 'side' continues to receive polling requests and, consequently, will continuously print an error.

You can see this effect on the client side in your browser when you disconnect your server and leave the client page open. If you look at the browser's error/console log what you should see is a continuous stream of *net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED* errors. By placing the disconnect event handler in the `.on('data', ...)` handler for your server, you are seeing the converse of this situation.

[net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGU1I.png)

Answer (score -1):

> This is basic code for socket.io
>
> The following example attaches socket.io to a plain Node.JS HTTP
>   server listening on port 3000.

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on('event', function(data){});
  client.on('disconnect', function(){});
});
server.listen(3000);
```

I think, you should try.

Comment: I according to the website to do，but  is the same result